# Getting connection timed out with DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to a remote rackspace DB
PHP:

```
<?php
  $servername = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";
   $dbname = "table";
    // Create connection
       $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
       if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
 ?>
```

And I get

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out

Comment: Is the mysql Server running?

Comment: Yes it is running

Comment: Do you have tried a restart?

Comment: YA just did it still getting same error

Comment: Can you connect to it with an 3rd party tool such as MYSQL workbench or Sequel pro?

Comment: YA I have copied the DB using workbench created in my local and made the page and now I uploaded that page on different server where I am calling this DB remotely and its throwing error

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 <?php
      $servername = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
       $username = "username";
       $password = "password";
       $dbname = "table";
        // Create connection
           $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
         // Check connection
           if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();die();

       } 
     ?>
```